# How to change a string which is like a list to list again?

Tags: python, string, list

I had a column in data frame that each cell contains the list of number, in order to groupby this col I change the format to string. now I want to count the number of this string list which is now grouped. I mean:

```
slist = x.sort_values('s_key').groupby('u_key', sort=False)['s_key'].unique()
slist = s_list.reset_index()

s_list.s_key=s_list.s_key.astype("str")
u_list = s_list.groupby('s_key', sort=False)['u_key'].apply(list).reset_index()

u_list['num_u'] = u_list['u_key'].str.len()
```

I can count the number of 'int' of u_key in the u_list but I can not get the right length or the right number of 'int' of s_key in the u_list. I also split but It gives me the wrong number. Is it possible when I change a type of list to str, I retrieve it back?

just imagine the s_key and u_key's elements are int at the first place

Comment: Did you try using `eval` ? Can you show some data please, just for ease of visualizing the problem.

Comment: `list(my_object)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the `list()` function to convert your string to a list.

```
your_list = list(your_string)
```